# O LINQ to Entities não reconhece o método 'Boolean Like?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, .net, linq

Estou tendo este erro ao tentar fazer uma com consulta usando LINQ to SQL
apos fazer as alterações sugeridas:

```
{SELECT
`Extent1`.`idcliente`, 
`Extent1`.`nome`, 
`Extent1`.`pai`, 
`Extent1`.`mae`, 
`Extent1`.`informacao`, 
`Extent1`.`datanascimento`, 
`Extent1`.`foto`
FROM `cliente` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE (LOCATE(TRIM(@p__linq__0), `Extent1`.`mae`)) = 1}
```

C#

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string recebeNome, int recebeOpcao)
    {


        try
        {
            sistema_mobileEntities dao = new sistema_mobileEntities();
            IQueryable<cliente> sql;
            sql = null;

            if (recebeOpcao == 1)
            {

                //link to sql não tem like
                sql = from c in dao.cliente
                      where c.nome.StartsWith(recebeNome.Trim())
                      // where SqlMethods.Like(c.nome, recebeNome.Trim() + "%")
                      select c;

                TempData["opcao1"] = "nome";
            }

            if (recebeOpcao == 2)
            {
                sql = from c in dao.cliente
                      where c.pai.StartsWith(recebeNome.Trim())
                      select c;

                TempData["opcao2"] = "pai";
            }

            if (recebeOpcao == 3)
            {
                sql = from c in dao.cliente
                      where c.mae.StartsWith(recebeNome.Trim())
                      select c;

                TempData["opcao3"] = "mae";
            }

            return View(sql.ToList());
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Erro ao consultar cliente" + ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Se você estivesse usando LINQ To SQL precisaria garantir que está usando o *namespace* com [`using System.Data.Linq.SqlClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Mas em LINQ To Entities não existe este método mesmo. Você teria que criar um método que simulasse um `LIKE` ou usar uma outra forma.

Neste caso específico poderia usar apenas

```
where c.nome.StartsWith(recebeNome.Trim())
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/LikeStart.cs).

Comment: Fiz a alteração do código, e tenho a consulta sql gerada! Só preciso saber se está correto desta forma.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SqlFunctions.PatIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex.aspx) ao invés de `SqlMethods.Like`, caso este não esteja disponível.

- A classe [`SqlFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) está definida no assembly `System.Data.Entity.dll`
- ao passo que a classe [`SqlMethods`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods(v=vs.110).aspx) está definida no assembly `System.Data.Linq.dll`

Comment: Usando o where c.nome.StartsWith(recebeNome.Trim()) 
eu tenho a resposta sql, só preciso saber se está correto:
{SELECT  Extent1.idcliente,  Extent1.nome,  Extent1.pai,  Extent1.mae, Extent1.informacao,  Extent1.datanascimento,  Extent1.foto FROM cliente AS Extent1 WHERE (LOCATE(TRIM(@p__linq__0), Extent1.mae)) = 1}

Comment: Qual é o sistema de banco de dados que está usando?

Comment: Estou usando o Banco Mysql